# Mining the SOLR query logfile to calculate top (most frequent) searches per mont

Tags: solr

I need to retrieve solr query stats which show for a given time period (say one month) how times that query term was searched.

I believe the first step is to enable logging which produces entries in the log file

Has anyone solved this? Is there some basic log file crunching code to spit out a list like
     eat   3000
     food  2020
     bread 1900

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself and most of all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [ask]

Comment: What I've seen internal code do is to extract the query itself (either from the Solr log or from the web frontend) and index each query as a document in a dedicated Solr core - together with the timestamp for when the query was made. That quickly allows you to facet on terms and apply date/term filters.

Comment: @matslindh I would think that would have quite a bit more overhead at query time for high vol servers rather than just a log process

Answer (score 0):

wanted to come back and answer myself.

I found a good github project that parses the log
   https://github.com/dfdeshom/solr-loganalyzer